# Get access token for matrix bridge

Tags: support, authentication, inbox

I want to build a bridge for my [matrix server](https://matrix.org/).
To read my inbox an `access_token` is required.
Do I really need to register an application just to get one access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do. The only way to get access token is via [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), and you need a registered application for that. What you **don't** need is a public post here to announce your application; that is only required for [write access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write). Just fill in the form [here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register).